# Resize event does not fire in Firefox, but I need to handle focus when FancyBox is shown

Tags: javascript, focus, fancybox

I am working on a solution where I need to have the first input field selected when a fancybox is shown. I have tried reacting to the resize event, which works fine in IE but not in Firefox. Also tried reacting to the click event on the link that opens the box - but aparently this is too early so some other element steals focus afterwards. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the onComplete callback:

```
$("#whatever").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#someTextBox').focus();
    }
});
```